# Is it a problem if my dryer vent slopes uphill through a crawl space?

Tags: dryer, ventilation

My dryer is vented through a crawl space and as it exits the space it will run up hill. Is this creating a problem by code or will it collect lint and moisture and clog prematurely?

Comment: How long is the entire vent? How many bends? How long is the sloped part, and what's the vertical distance?

Comment: I would think lint balls would be your only issue where it raises. Once a year cleaning that be done on all dryer vents should be good. + up north.

Answer (score 2):

The International Residential Code (IRC 2009) has no restrictions or requirements for clothes-dryer exhaust ducts to have any pitch, either up or down, although they are also required to conform to the "dryer manufacturer's installation instructions".

Answer (score 0):

Always run dryer vent piping a at least a 3% grade to the outside to allow any moisture to run to the exterior to the building ,  " common sense and 55 years in the industry"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Does significant amounts of moisture accumulate in dryer ducting? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.